# Is there a way to measure the amount power of visible light against a surface?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light

If you were to hypothetically shine a single beam of light that is specific in its power source and output efficiency against a wall across a specific measurable distance. Is there a possible way to measure the amount of visible observable light against the surface when it finally reaches said surface over a specific pre-defined distance?

Any help or what type of subject matter this applies to would be appreciated. Trying to learn about such topics. I assume it has to do with the speed of light. Any formula or documentation that might be helpful and appreciated as well.

The light and the object it shines against are not moving and static in position.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like you are asking for an _incident light meter._  I only know them from photography: e.g., https://www.bhphotovideo.com/find/Product_Resources/lightmeters1.jsp .  I imagine that for a physics experiment, you would want one that was calibrated in some different units than f stops and shutter speeds.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're looking for experimental techniques. You can use a [photodiode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photodiode) to measure power. For selecting visible light you could use one or more cut-off [filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infrared_cut-off_filter). There also exists [monochromatic filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochromator) that select specific wavelengths, if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks for the response.